# zmq subscriber fails to receive message when subscriber is restarted

Tags: node.js, zeromq, publish-subscribe

I have **`PUB/SUB`** program using `zmq` broker ( `node.js` ).

Subscriber **doesn't** receive messages while subscriber is restarted and publisher is still publishing the messages. But `PUB/SUB` is working fine when both publisher and subscriber services are started naturally. Reason behind this is unknown.

**What could possibly be wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is impossible to cover exactly a case of an undisclosed MCVE-design of using a **`PUB`**-archetype, on Publisher side, and an unspecified number of **`SUB`**-archetype nodes on the Subscribers' sides, there is one important fact.

### The Design

Yes, the Design. Having read the API, user will be sure that

- ZeroMQ does not guarrantee a message delivery
- ZeroMQ **`PUB`**-lisher does not wait and publishes a message for all connected **`SUB`**-scribers, not waiting for late-joiners, nor providing any queue/persistence for not connected `SUB`-scribers and discards all messages that were requested to `PUB`-lish during times there are no `SUB`-s connected.

---

[image]